# How do I search only the displayed part of concealed text?

Tags: search, conceal

If I have syntax highlighting rules setup using `conceal` to hide or change certain characters in a file, how do I search what is displayed, as opposed to what the buffer actually contains?

The concealed part may contain formatting markup, for example, which I wish to ignore.

I'd like a method that:

- doesn't rely on the specific rules used to create the concealed text.
- provides some level of compatibility with the traditional search operators like `n`, `*`, etc.

Can this be done without re-implementing `n`, `*` and the like?

Related:

- [How can I copy the displayed text, instead of the actual text?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5524/205)

Comment: testing [help/behavior].

Answer (score 3):

This is not really possible, as concealing was meant as a sole method for displaying chars instead of the actual content. In the same sense, you can't really search for what has been folded or signs. The only method I know is using `screenchar()` function as shown in my other answer, but that is not really ready to use.

Comment: While it's true I can't search for what has been folded, by using `'foldopen'`, I can tell Vim to match at most once in a folded region, so there are small steps in that direction. Anyway, what's the stance on `conceal`? Is there hope of seeing such functionality implemented?

Comment: true, but you still couldn't search for what is returned by `foldtext()`. Anyways, you might want to suggest an improvement at vim-dev ml and see what Bram thinks, but my feeling is, this won't be implemented anytime soon since there are still too many bugs/particularities with conceal mode today and nobody really looked for fixing it. I did try once, but it was complicated and broke in subtle ways.